# sql get previous row value for a running total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is already calculating a running total for new clients and clients that have left. However if there are no new clients or no clients have left when I try to plot this on a graph I get blank spaces.

How can I get the previous years figures if a year is null?

```
select x.Year
        , case when x.TotalClients is null then 0 else x.TotalClients end as 'TotalNewClients'
        , x.RunningTotal as 'RunningTotalNewClients'
        , case when x2.TotalClients is null then 0 else x2.TotalClients end as 'TotalLeftClients'
        , x2.RunningTotal as  'RunningTotalLeftClients'
from (
        SELECT
            st1.YearStart as 'Year',
            st1.TotalClients,
            RunningTotal = SUM(st2.TotalClients)
        FROM
            @TotalsStart AS st1
        INNER JOIN
            @TotalsStart AS st2
            ON st2.YearStart <= st1.YearStart
        GROUP BY st1.YearStart, st1.TotalClients) as x
left outer join 
        (SELECT
            st1.YearStart  as 'Year',
            st1.TotalClients,
            RunningTotal = SUM(st2.TotalClients)
        FROM
            @TotalsEnd AS st1
        INNER JOIN
            @TotalsEnd AS st2
            ON st2.YearStart <= st1.YearStart
        GROUP BY st1.YearStart, st1.TotalClients
        ) as x2 on x.Year = x2.Year
Order by x.Year
```

Comment: Maybe the lag function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) can help you ?

Comment: thanks I will have a look at that, not heard of the lag function before

Comment: Ah that lag function worked a treat, I just had to amend one of the lines in my select statement to the following, thanks for the help :)

, case when x2.RunningTotal is null then lag(x2.RunningTotal,1,0) over(order by x.year) else x2.RunningTotal end as  'RunningTotalLeftClients'

Comment: Really? That's nice, it was a gamble. I will place it as an anwser if you don't mind :)

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2012 then you can do a running total by using a window function: `sum(totalClients) over (partition by ... order by ..)`. The `order by` in the `over` clause makes it a running total

Comment: will have a look at the running total as well than thanks, as should make the query a bit more simple then too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the lag function (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) can help you?

Comment: a link is not what i consider an answer

Comment: Ive posted my working code so you can see how I used the Lag function

Answer (score 0):

This was my amended code, I changed 2 lines in the select to use the lag function, I used the link in my answer to get this working.

```
select x.Year
        , case when x.TotalClients is null then 0 else x.TotalClients end as 'TotalNewClients'
        , x.RunningTotal 
        , case when x.RunningTotal is null then lag(x.RunningTotal,1,0) over(order by x.year) else x.RunningTotal end as  'RunningTotalNewClients'
        , case when x2.TotalClients is null then 0 else x2.TotalClients end as 'TotalLeftClients'
        , x2.RunningTotal
        , case when x2.RunningTotal is null then lag(x2.RunningTotal,1,0) over(order by x.year) else x2.RunningTotal end as  'RunningTotalLeftClients'
from (
        SELECT
            st1.YearStart as 'Year',
            st1.TotalClients,
            RunningTotal = SUM(st2.TotalClients)
        FROM
            @TotalsStart AS st1
        INNER JOIN
            @TotalsStart AS st2
            ON st2.YearStart <= st1.YearStart
        GROUP BY st1.YearStart, st1.TotalClients) as x
left outer join 
        (SELECT
            st1.YearStart  as 'Year',
            st1.TotalClients,
            RunningTotal = SUM(st2.TotalClients)
        FROM
            @TotalsEnd AS st1
        INNER JOIN
            @TotalsEnd AS st2
            ON st2.YearStart <= st1.YearStart
        GROUP BY st1.YearStart, st1.TotalClients
        ) as x2 on x.Year = x2.Year
Order by x.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is way to complicated if you are using SQL Server 2012+.  Just use the cumulative sum functionality:

```
select coalesce(x.Year, x2.year) as year,
       coalesce(x.TotalClients, 0 ) as TotalNewClients,
       x.RunningTotal as RunningTotalNewClients
       coalesce(x2.TotalClients, 0) as TotalLeftClients,
       x2.RunningTotal as RunningTotalLeftClients
from (SELECT st.YearStart as Year, st.TotalClients,
             SUM(st.TotalClients) over (order by year) as RunningTotal
      FROM @TotalsStart st
     ) x full outer join 
     (SELECT st.YearStart  as Year, st.TotalClients,
             SUM(st.TotalClients) over (order by year) as RunningTotal
      FROM @TotalsEnd AS st
    ) x2
    on x.Year = x2.Year
Order by coalesce(x.Year, x2.year);
```

Even in earlier versions of SQL Server, `apply` is a better method for getting cumulative sums than `join` with `group by`.

By the way, you should use single quotes only for string and date constants, not for column aliases.  Although allowed in that context, they generally lead to confusion and hard-to-find errors in the query.